# How to use discord API to track historical server member_count

Tags: discord

I know that I can request

```
url='https://discord.com/api/v8/guilds/GUILD_ID?with_counts=true'
```

and then get 'approximate_member_count', 'approximate_presence_count' in the json object, but I am wondering if I can call this API and get historical member count of the server in anyway?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, the [API documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild) for the guild resource does not mention a way to retrieve the historical member count of a particular server, only the current member count.